# Libre Writer showing only blank icons, how to get the file menu (and tools to change setting)

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice, settings

I recently opened Libre Write (LibreOffice), and noticed that the entire top bar is just a set of icons. I can get to a more contextual menu by right clicking the top bar, but "file", "tools", "settings" are all missing, doesn't seem to be a way to change the top bar to not be icons.

How would I go about changing this to contain a context menu?

[image: Picture of image]

Comment: You can try updating Libreoffice with the official Libreoffice Fresh PPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling `libreoffice-gtk3` seemed to revert the app view to something with proper menus as an intermediate solution.

Actual solution: `sudo apt remove indicator-applet-appmenu` fixed it so the menus have returned.